# Как добавить опциональную поддержку сторонней библиотеки?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, зависимости

У меня есть класс, принимающий в конструкторе матрицы моей же библиотеки:

```
struct MatrixSolver {
  MatrixSolver(const my::Matrix& mtx);
}
```

Теперь я хочу добавить поддержку реализации матриц сторонней библиотеки для удобства пользователей, например, `Eigen::MatrixXd`. В будущем могут понадобиться и другие библиотеки. Если просто добавить конструктор с этим параметром, то мой `MatrixSolver` получит безусловную зависимость `Eigen` и люди, у которых не поставлен `Eigen`, не смогут его использовать. **Как сделать опциональную поддержку этой библиотеки?**

Если просто сделать произвольный шаблонный параметр и использовать методы `Eigen::MatrixXd`, то возникают следующие проблемы: 1) как добавить поддержку другой библиотеки в будущем?; 2) невнятные ошибки при использовании не `Eigen::MatrixXd` этим конструктором; 3) нет поддержки преобразуемых в `Eigen::MatrixXd` типов, только непосредственно таких, члены которых используются в шаблоне.

Ещё один известный вариант — сделать проверку `#ifdef EIGEN_INCLUDE_GUARD` и только тогда добавлять конструктор. Но с этим вариантом возникает проблема с порядком включения хедеров:

```
#include "eigen.h"
#include "matrix_solver.h"
```

не то же самое, что и

```
#include "eigen.h"
#include "matrix_solver.h"
```

И ещё есть вариант с явным указанием, как компилировать мою библиотеку: `-DSOLVER_WITH_EIGEN` и проверкой этого условия. Работает нормально, но проблема в явном указании и перекомпиляции библиотеки для разных пользователей, чего хотелось бы избежать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вынесите функции, предоставляющие поддержку Eigen, в отдельный заголовочный файл (обычно такие файлы помещают в каталог ext). Если пользователю будет нужно - он подключит этот файл.

Если у вашего класса есть метод, который который может принимать объекты Eigen, и его нельзя вынести в отдельный файл - делайте этот метод шаблонным, и используйте SFINAE/концепты. Например:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct matrix_traits{
    static constexpr bool is_matrix = false;
};

class MyClass{
template<typename Matrix, std::enable_if_t<matrix_traits<std::decay_t<Matrix>>::is_matrix, bool> = true>
    void setMatrix(Matrix&& matrix){
        using traits = matrix_traits<std::decay_t<Matrix>>;
        std::size_t rowCount = traits::rowCount(matrix);
        std::size_t colCount = traits::colCount(matrix);
    }
};
```

А затем в `ext/eigen.hpp` добавте специализацию:

```cpp
template<> struct matrix_traits<Eigen::MatrixXd>{ // лучше поддерживать шаблонную матрицу Eigen, но я не помню, как она выглядит

    static constexpr bool is_matrix = true;
    static std::size_t rowCount(const Eigen::MatrixXd& m){
       return m.rows();
    }
    static std::size_t colCount(const Eigen::MatrixXd& m){
       return m.cols();
    }
}
```

UPD: один из вариантов поддержки шаблонных классов Eigen:

```cpp
namespace my_ns{
template<class D>
std::true_type is_eigen_matrix(const Eigen::MatrixBase<D>&){ return{}; }

template<typename M> struct matrix_traits<
     M, std::void_t<decltype(my_ns::is_eigen_matrix(std::declval<M>()))>>{
  /* ... */
};
}
```

При перегрузке функций, подобных `is_eigen_matrix`, важно указать пространство имён, иначе случайно может подойти функция из другой библиотеки.

Другой вариант - использовать специализацию для `std::is_constructable<Eigen::MatrixXd, M>::value`. Но это плохой вариант, т.к. типы, преобразуемые в Eigen, могут не предоставлять нужный интерфейс, а если преобразовать этот тип в `Eigen::MatrixXd`, будет бессмысленное выделение динамической памяти.

Comment: При таком варианте остаётся проблема с преобразуемыми к `Eigen::MatrixXd` типами. Либо для всех них надо добавлять отдельную специализацию. Ещё есть (менее важная) проблема — для каждого нового типа элемента матрицы (и размеров, если они статические) будет генерится новый конструктор, что негативно влияет на скорость компиляции и размер исходника. Это негативные отличия шаблонного параметра от того, если бы мы просто написали конструктор с `const Eigen::MatrixXd&`.

Comment: @Сергей , обновил. В документации Eigen вроде где-то подробнее написано про работу с шаблонными типами, я привёл только общий подход.

Comment: @Сергей , на счет негативных последствий - смиритесь, это c++. Eigen::MatrixXd даже не является типом, это псевдоним, для него нельзя сделать предварительное объявление. А если бы и можно было, это привело бы к затратам времени выполнения (зачем выделять память для массивов фиксированного размера?). Единственный способ не использовать шаблонные методы - не использовать методы вообще. Вы можете использовать свободные функции, и вы можете добавлять перегрузки этих функций  вв `ext/eigen.cpp`, Но цену шаблонов вам всё еще нужно заплатить, т.к. Eigen сам по себе шаблонный.

Answer (score 0):

Наличие стороннего заголовка можно проверить и затем действовать по обстоятельствам:

```
#if __has_include(<eigen.h>)
#include <eigen.h>
#define MYLIB_USES_EIGEN
#endif

...
struct MatrixSolver
{
#ifdef MYLIB_USES_EIGEN
  MatrixSolver(Eigen::MatrixXd const & mat)
  {
    ...
  }
#endif
```

Comment: Здесь проблема может быть с тем, что пользователь может иметь в системе установленную `Eigen` как зависимость другого проекта, но это не значит, что он хочет её использовать в моей библиотеке. То есть ошибок не будет, т.к. она есть, но будет лишний оверхед, если использовать не хочет. А, и получается, что он линковаться обязан даже если не использует (в случае не хедер-онли библиотеки)?

Comment: @Сергей Никакого оверхеда не будет. Если он не будет использовать конструктор и прочие методы, испозующие eigen, то они и не будут задействоваться и даже не попадут в финальный бинарь

Comment: Почему не будет? Ведь мы включаем хедер, увеличиваем длительность компиляции и размер исходника, хотя ничего из него не используем. Да, неиспользуемые шаблоны не попадут, но остальное должно попасть.

Comment: @Сергей Оверхед - это бесполезно потраченные вычислительные ресурсы при работе приложения. *"остальное должно попасть"* - нет, с чего бы это? Разве если специально включить принудительное оставление неиспользуемого кода. Ну а если вы не хотите увеличивать длительность компиляции за счет атоматического включения заголовочного файла eigen при его наличии, то директиву `MYLIB_USES_EIGEN` должен задавать пользователь. однако на это вы в вопросе уже жаловались *"то проблема в явном указании"*. Стоит определиться, что вы вообще хотите.

Comment: Хотелось бы идеального решения без проблем)

Comment: @Сергей Для этого вам надо прекратить себе придумывать эти проблемы. А то сейчас получается, что когда подключение библиотеки производит пользователь вручную, вы жалуетесь, что она не подключается автоматически, а если она подключается автоматически, то вы жалуетесь, что она не подключается пользователем вручную.